# Install dependent project from git repositroy

Tags: php, json, git, yii2, composer-php

I have some trouble with dependency of composer. My basic project has the following json file:

```
"require": {
    "klabs/side-menu-widget": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:klabsers/side-menu-widget.git"
    }
]
```

And **klabs/side-menu-widget** has the following composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "klabs/side-menu-widget",
    "description": "Responsive side menu widget for Yii 2 framework",
    "type": "yii2-extension",
    "keywords": [
        "yii",
        "extension",
        "widget",
        "yii2",
        "yii 2",
        "menu",
        "bootstrap"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/klabsers/side-menu-widget/overview",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "authors": [
    {
        "name": "Urmat Zhenaliev",
        "email": "sonkei@ya.ru",
        "homepage": "http://prosoft.kg",
        "role": "Developer"
    }
    ],
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://bitbucket.org/klabsers/side-menu-widget/issues",
        "source": "https://bitbucket.org/klabsers/side-menu-widget"
    },
    "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "klabs/font-awesome-asset": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "klabs\\widgets\\menu\\side\\": ""
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:klabsers/font-awesome-asset.git"
    }
    ]
}
```

Take a not to

```
"require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "klabs/font-awesome-asset": "dev-master"
},
```

This project (klabs/side-menu-widget) requires another git repository named **klabs/font-awesome-asset**, that has the following composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "klabs/font-awesome-asset",
    "description": "Font Awesome css framework asset manager for Yii 2 framework",
    "type": "yii2-extension",
    "keywords": [
        "yii",
        "extension",
        "widget",
        "asset",
        "assets",
        "yii2",
        "yii 2",
        "menu",
        "font",
        "font-awesome",
        "awesome"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/klabsers/font-awesome-asset/overview",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "authors": [
    {
        "name": "Urmat Zhenaliev",
        "email": "sonkei@ya.ru",
        "homepage": "http://prosoft.kg",
        "role": "Developer"
    }
    ],
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://bitbucket.org/klabsers/font-awesome-asset/issues",
        "source": "https://bitbucket.org/klabsers/font-awesome-asset"
    },
    "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "klabs\\assets\\font_awesome\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to install **klabs/side-menu-widget** I get the error:

[image]
And my quiestion is - 
Is it available to autoload git respository dependency without including it in my basic project and if yes what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seem that child composer file is ignored
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories

> Repositories are not resolved recursively. You can only add them to your main composer.json